# How to fix fetch returning 404 when reaching for a php file in react native?

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, fetch, backend

I am currently learning React Native. In order to do it, I'm trying to make a log in screen. I have only a login screen right now, and I want to connect it with a .php file that will connect to a database and check for the user and password. I usually use XMLHttpRequest for this connection, but someone told me that it's better to use fetch on React Native (and regardless, both ran into the exact same problem: the status of the request is always 404 and it never seems to find the .php file.

```
logInProcess  = () => {  
    var respond = "";
    var logInValues = {
      login: this.state.user,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    fetch('./backend/login.php', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(logInValues)
    }).then( (response) => {
        respond = response.json();
        console.log(response.status)
        console.log(respond);
      }
    )
  };
```

Right now, this code is merely supposed to showcase the connection to the database working. I'll only add further stuff to it later, but right now, I need to fix this 404 problem.

Comment: perhaps the URL is incorrect - check the path in your PHP server

Comment: Check your server is running.

Comment: @Jaromanda I am suspecting it might be that. I am using the relative path to do this, but I wonder whether I can use relative paths for this

Comment: perhaps it's just `/login.php` - i.e `/backend` is the "file root"?

Comment: The ``login.php`` file was inside the ``/backend`` folder in the root where this js code was, which is what I was trying. Right now, I'm checking if leaving everything in the same folder will help.
@ravibagul91 I believe my server is running. I am using expo to run the application, and the lab is open, it's even running on my phone, so I suppose the server is ok. Then again, I'm new to web development, so I might be assuming wrongly.

Comment: so, have you even tried what I suggested?

Comment: I was trying some other things . I only just noticed your suggestion about the php server. I am not sure how to do that. If you are talking about checking the environment variables, then I'm checking the paths there now.

Comment: Just to reiterate, you can't call a PHP file local to your app code. If you are making a HTTP request to an API, you would need it to be running on a server online or accessible on your local network. So in your case, the server side PHP file would need to be hosted on that server and called something like `https://yourwebsite.com/backend/login.php` or `http://0.0.0.0:1234/backend/login.php` where the IP address is that of your local server

Comment: Just as an addition. The flow of data should be `user input on app` => `app pushes data to api` => `api receives the data` => `api stores/acts on the data perhaps via a database`. The app is a separate system to the API and database (if you need one)

Comment: @scgough Oh, okay, I see. I thought that the php file was being hosted together with the actual app (since they were in the same folder) in the Expo Client. But if that's it, I'll put the files in my xampp/apache server and try to access from there.

Comment: @scgough Ok, that actually worked. Sort of. It no longer says anything about a 404 error, instead it returns an error like ``NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource``. I am researching about it now.

Comment: Great. Sounds like your on the right track. 

Comment: @scgough Ok, it more or lesss worked now. I mean, it connects to the database by using a connection to a local server. Honestly, I wish I knew how to host the app and the php files in the same server, but for now, I'm happy with this, since it will let me test my code. Thanks to everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have used "./" instead of "/"

```
logInProcess  = () => {  
var respond = "";
var logInValues = {
  login: this.state.user,
  password: this.state.password
}

fetch('/backend/login.php', {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(logInValues)
}).then( (response) => {
    respond = response.json();
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(respond);
  }
)
};
```

Comment: It is not that. I already tried that, and it still returns 404

Comment: @AugustoCezar see my comment above